# db2 case/cast declaration issue

Tags: sql, excel, db2

My database includes a "vendor invoice number" column.  This column contains both strings and integers.  Because Excel and Db2 don't get along so well, I am attempting to format the data upon output, so as to automate my reports.  Here is the code that works, but I want to understand why it's not working as intended when I modify the code.

```
CASE
  WHEN substring(vendor_invoice_number,1,1) = 0 or
       lcase(substring(vendor_invoice_number,1,1)) between 'a' and 'z'
  THEN TRIM(vendor_invoice_number)               
END as "invoice",
cast(vendor_invoice_number as INT)
```

This works by giving me 2 columns, then I manipulate with an IF(ISNA function in Excel to choose the correct column.

If I move `cast(vendor_invoice_number as INT)` into the CASE statement as an `ELSE`, then I lose all string invoice numbers, all leading zeros, and it turns everything in that column into an INTEGER, even if the WHEN statements are true.

Why?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 or any other RDBMS for that matter don't allow returning different types in the same column.

Your DB column is a string, you'll just need to return it as such.

The real question is how are you getting from the SQL select to Excel?

If you're querying an external table, Excel shouldn't be trying to reformat it.

There are various tools available to generate XLS/XLSX directly on the IBM i from an SQL statement that should also leave it as a string.